# How to pass a new array as arguments to a method in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arguments

I am trying to pass an array of boolean values to a method. This code works:

```
void checkResults(boolean[] isChecked){
  //Do something
}

     boolean[] isChecked= {true, true};
     checkResults(isChecked); //works
```

But all attempts below failed:

```
     checkResults(new {true, true}); //Compile time error
     checkResults({true, true});     //Compile time error
     checkResults(true, true);       //Compile time error (this one is obvious)
```

Is there a way to create an array in arguments and pass to a method in one line?

Comment: Have you tried `checkResults(new boolean[]{true, true})`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an anonymous array like this and pass the same.

```
checkResults(new boolean[]{true, true});
```